# Хочу сделать уведомление (напоминание) в день один раз в одно и тоже время

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notificationIsActive"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        self.message.text=@"Напоминание включено";


        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:date];
        components.calendar = calendar;
        components.hour = 7;
        components.minute = 37;
        date = components.date;

        if([date compare:[NSDate date]] < 0) {
            date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
        }

        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        localNotification.alertBody = @"ТЕКСТ НАПОМИНАНИЯ";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;//NSCalendarUnitMinute; //Repeating instructions here.
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    }
```

Comment: так вопрос в чем? как сконвертировать 10 утра в NSDate?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Mikheyenko, Да, Каждый день в 10 утра

Comment: а весь этот код зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Грубо говоря вот так найти время (с учетом, что будильник может ставиться до 10 утра или после)

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:date];
components.calendar = calendar;
components.hour = 10;
components.minute = 0;
date = components.date;

if([date compare:[NSDate date]] < 0) {
    date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
}
```

чтобы повторять его каждый день

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
```